# How to add .so file in tizen

Tags: samsung-mobile, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, .so

I'm new to tizen platform. I have a .so file. Is it possible to use .so file's in tizen native, web or hybrid app? If yes, can you please guide me how to use, it would be helpful for me to complete my task.

Answer (score 1):

After research so much of time, I found solution

If we want to use .so file in Tizen, then you have to compile source code with an appropriate hardware architecture. You can add .so file directly to your main project.

Lets assume you have two applications:

1. TestLibrary (shared library)
2. TestApplication (which wants to use a .so file)

**Procedure:**

1. Copy the header files of shared library (in the example : TestLibrary/inc)to TestApplication's inc folder.
2. keep the .so file (in our example: liborg.example.testlibrary.so) in TestApplication's lib folder
3. Show library path as following:

   a. Open TestApplication's properties window

   b. C/C++ Build -> Settings

   c. C++ Linker -> Libraries

   d. In "Libraries(-l)" section click add and put the .so file's name excluding .so and lib (in my example: org.example.testlibrary)
4. Now use the .so files' functions by including the header files in your TestApplication.

Comment: Could you please make some screen shoot of these steps please, I can't find these option in my tizen generated project, I open it with visual studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

for 1. I would suggest to add usr/include dir and add it to compiler path,

you'll find an example at:

https://wiki.iotivity.org/tizen